# Bootstrap dropdown issues on mobile touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I've created a mobile menu over the bootstrap dropdown resource.

It must work this way: when you click on hamburger menu icon, it open, and if you click on close icon, or outside of the menu items, it close.

At desktop with a mouse cursor it works fine, but with the mobile touch the menu close automatically when you click on the menu items.

Follow the demo below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/UNs9J/6344/

My script:

```
// Insert class on the body when mobile menu is opened 

$(function() {
  $('.no-touch .main-header__nav .dropdown.mmenu').on('click', function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $('body').removeClass('mmenu-opened');
    } else {

      $('body').addClass('mmenu-opened');
    }

  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.touch .main-header__nav .dropdown.mmenu').on('tap', function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $('body').removeClass('mmenu-opened');
    } else {

      $('body').addClass('mmenu-opened');
    }

  });
});

$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', function(){

    if ($('.main-header__nav .mmenu').hasClass("open")) {
      $('body').removeClass('mmenu-opened');
    }

  });
});
```

I don't know what to do anymore. If anyone help me I'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question - you don't want to close the menu on selection of an item?  If so, I think you just need to stop propagation of the event.  Here is the [modified js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60x4b9x9/1/).

Here is the JS code with the change...

```
$(function() {
  $('.no-touch .main-header__nav .dropdown.mmenu').on('click', function(event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $('body').removeClass('mmenu-opened');
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {

      $('body').addClass('mmenu-opened');
    }

  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.touch .main-header__nav .dropdown.mmenu').on('tap', function(event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $('body').removeClass('mmenu-opened');
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {

      $('body').addClass('mmenu-opened');
    }

  });
});
```

Note I passed in the `event` variable to the event handlers and then called stopPropagation() when the menu is open.  Is this the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's still closing when I touch over a menu item =/.

Comment: shucks, I guess I did not get things clear.  I took a look again at your fiddle and was having a hard time understanding the behavioral differences between the touch and non-touch.  Currently, when I try your fiddle on my laptop and I click a menu item (to open a submenu for instance), the menu closes.  I also get the same behavior whether I remove all your javascript or not.  I am probably missing something important - sorry!  One thing I did notice is that there are a few errors on the console on the external javascript includes.  could that be part of your culprit?

Comment: hello Darry, I make a gif to show you. How it should work and is working on desktop browser with cursor: http://s22.postimg.org/tfw7hv3of/ezgif_com_crop_2.gif - and how it's working on a mobile device with touch http://s27.postimg.org/44hmt8cmp/ezgif_com_crop_3.gif (same problem on iOS) - Thanks in advance

Comment: I see the problem now - good examples!  So, I think I have a clue as to the problem.  I added some console.log() statements to your javascript.  It turns out your handlers are never getting initialized - and therefore they are never being invoked when a click or tap happens.  see [link] ( http://jsfiddle.net/darrylivan/UNs9J/6360/ ) .  If you look at the console when you run it, you should see ` console.log('initializing handlers')` put out to the log twice as they are called right before each handler initialization, but they are not.  I suspect it is because of the syntax error in main.min.js

Comment: Hey Derry! First I want to thank you again for all the support. I fixed the main.min.js error, but unfortunately the menu behaviour is still the same on the touch =/

Comment: okay - that is easier to debug with that fix.  So, it looks like your dropdown menus are not implemented using bootstrap.  the top level navbar is a bootstrap element, but there is no `data-toggle="dropdown"` on the relevant sub-menu items.  that is not necessarily incorrect - but I don't think this is a bootstrap issue.  based on the classes, it looks like it might be dlMenu - [link] (http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Responsive-Multi-Level-Menu-Plugin-Dlmenu.html ) .  Is that what you are using for the 'inner' menu?

Comment: Exactly! I'm using the bootstrap dropdown to toggle that ul area, and inside it the dlMenu to enjoy the multilevel menu feature.

Comment: I found a solution! I added the "stopPropagation" inside the inner items instead the tap function! Overall thanks a lot for all attention!

Comment: great!  glad you sorted it out.